# Is there .net implementation of TeX

Tags: .net, tex

T<sub>E</sub>X is a typesetting system written by Donald E. Knuth. [MiKT<sub>E</sub>X](http://miktex.org/about) is an up-to-date implementation of T<sub>E</sub>X and related programs for Windows (all current variants).

Is there .NET implementation of T<sub>E</sub>X?

Comment: Why does it matter which language it is implemented in?

Comment: There is a number of Pascal implementations for .NET, so in theory it should be possible to compile the WEB code (into an unverifiable/unsafe CLI, of course).

Comment: Might work: http://blog.noldorin.com/2010/04/rendering-tex-math-in-wpf/

Comment: Is there C# implementations? and can run at an asp.net webpage.

Comment: To idstam: Thanks! but blog.noldorin.com/2010/04/rendering-tex-math-in-wpf – idstam can't be run under asp.net website, right?

Comment: @jalf No specific language is mentioned in the question. .NET isn't a language, it's a platform with a set of languages native to it.